# Faulty Allocation of Vector of Structures? Code not working

Tags: c++, vector, breadth-first-search

My Code is not working after the marked point.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

struct node{
  int data;
  int level;
};
int main()
{
    node x;
    x.data=0;
    int j=0;
    int n;
    int strt,lv=1;
    cout<<"Enter No. of Nodes: ";
    cin>>n;
    vector<node> adj[n];
    int m,data,nb=0;
    while(j<n)
    {
        cout<<"Enter No. of Neighbours of "<<j<<": ";
        cin>>m;
        while(nb<m)
        {
            cin>>x.data;
            x.level=0;
            adj[j].push_back(x);
            nb++;
        }
        nb=0;
        j++;
    }
    vector<node>::iterator i;
    /*for(j=0;j<n;++j)
    {   
        cout<<j;
        for(i=adj[j].begin();i!=adj[j].end();i++)
        {
            cout<<"->"<<(*(i)).data;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }*/
    node y,z;
    cout<<"Enter Starting Node: ";
    cin>>strt;    //This Point-*****************************
    cout<<"LOL";
    y.data=strt;
    y.level=0;
    vector<node> frontier;
    vector<node> next;
    frontier.push_back(y);
    while(!frontier.empty())
    {
        z=frontier.back();
        frontier.pop_back();
        //next.clear();
        for(i=adj[z.data].begin();i!=adj[z.data].end();i++)
        {
            if((*(i)).level==lv-1)
            {   (*(i)).level=lv;
                next.push_back((*(i)));
            }
        }
        frontier=next;
        lv++;
    }

    for(i=next.begin();i!=next.end();i++)
    {
        cout<<(*(i)).data<<" ";
    }
     return 0;
}
```

The terminal continues to take inputs as if the program is in infinite loop-But it is not stuck in infinite loop because the cout<<"LOL" statement is not executed even though while debugging the code the interpreter reads cout<<"LOL" and goes to the next line. Please Help.

Comment: that's a contradiction. if it's an infinite loop in the input, you'll never reach LOL.

Comment: That's what I am saying! Its not an infinite loop, but its still behaving as one!

Comment: If the frontier never becomes empty, it's going to be an infinite loop...

Comment: You wrote tag `bfs`. But your argorithm is not `bfs`. For `bfs` you must use `queue`.

Comment: I reached LOL by entering the following set of params

`[yanivx@ubuntu:~/stack]$ ./a.out
Enter No. of Nodes: 1
Enter No. of Neighbours of 0: 0
Enter Starting Node: 0
LOL[`

Comment: I have done changes to the code it is not in infinite loop now but gives a segfault don't know the reason for it though and at the third iteration. A small clue may be. Have added my own debug code can share if you need the new code

`Enter No. of Nodes: 1
Enter No. of Neighbours of 0: 1
1
Enter Starting Node: 1
LOL
Before push_back
After push_back
inside for loop
inside for loop
inside for loop
Segmentation fault`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are not clearing vector **next**, you are keeping next in **frontier** in each iteration of last **while** loop. So **frontier** becomes never empty. So your code falls in an infinite loop.

Just remove your comment sign before

```
next.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cout<<"LOL"<<endl;` to flush the output.

Trust the debugger. If it goes to the next line, the statement was executed.

Comment: Still Not Working. Now "LOL" is printed but the code is behaving in the same manner!

Comment: Of course...... perhaps post a new question? We cannot fix your code because we don't know what it is supposed to do. But then again, use the debugger...

Comment: Its the code for BFS(Breadth First Search) using STL. It is creating a Adjacency List using a 2D vector for making a graph and then applying BFS on the the graph inputted by user. Anyways, Thanks..

Comment: this is not the right place to tell that info. update the question or post a new one.